# Mongod process not starting

Tags: mongodb, server, wiredtiger, server-monitoring

Mongod process shutting down while starting with following error

exception in initAndListen: Location40414: BSON field 'MinValidDocument.t' is missing but a required field, terminating

Comment: What's the full message, and what comes before and after this line?

Comment: Hi @kevinadi thanks for replying ... there's nothing on before and after line this exception line came from nowhere